# Test prevProps in componentDidUpdate in React via Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

Having following code:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps: JsonInputProps) {
  if (prevProps.value !== this.props.value) {
    this.validateJsonSchema(this.props.value || '');
  }
}
```

and test code:

```
  it('componentDidUpdate should mount', () => {
    const onChange = jest.fn();
    const event = { target: { value: 'simulate-event' } };
    const wrapper = enzyme
      .shallow(<JsonInput onChange={onChange} onValueChange={mockOnValueChange}/>)
      .simulate('change', event);
    wrapper.setProps({ value: 'example' });
    expect(onChange).toBeCalled;
  });
```

and test coverage:

[image]

I got 'else path not taken' and I do NOT want to ignore the else path but dunno how to change props. Any idea?

Comment: coverage is overrated

Comment: You can just pass in props that dont have value prop in it and that should cover else  case like `wrapper.setProps({ foo: 'example' });`, if that dont work pass in the same value and also another prop with it

Comment: @Rikin "wrapper.setProps({ value: 'simulate-event', foo: 'something' });" did not help ;/

Comment: what if you dont pass the value at all and just pass in `foo: 'something'`

Comment: @Rikin Works! Thanks!

Comment: updated my answer, glad it worked out. Upvote and accept if you like, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cover else case you can pass in same prop value along with possibly something else along with it so that it covers else case upon update.

```
  it('componentDidUpdate should mount', () => {
    const onChange = jest.fn();
    const event = { target: { value: 'simulate-event' } };
    const wrapper = enzyme
      .shallow(<JsonInput onChange={onChange} onValueChange={mockOnValueChange}/>)
      .simulate('change', event);
    wrapper.setProps({ foo: 'something' });
    expect(onChange).toBeCalled;
  });
```